# Spring @Transactional method throws org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException non-transactional error

Tags: java, spring, server-sent-events

I have this method which is supposed to retrieve data from a repository using streams and then work through those results and sent server sent event messages. I was able to get this to work with a simple "sent, wait()" and then repeat so I don't think this is any issue with the way I construct the ExecutorService. I have the slight suspicion that it might have something to do with the fact that the executor runs asynchronous but I am unsure.

```
  @Transactional()
  public UUID createNewDataStream(Requests information) {
    sseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(86400000L);
    ExecutorService sseMvcExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
    sseStreams.put(id, emitter);
    List<Datastream> datastreams = sensorService
        .getDatastreams(information.getSensors().get(0), information.getStart(),
            information.getEnd()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    sseMvcExecutor.execute(() -> {
      try {
        while (true) {
          for (Datastream d : datastreams) {
            try (Stream<Observation> observations = observationRepository
                .findObservationsByDatastreamIdAndPhenomenonStartAfterAndPhenomenonEndBefore(
                    d.getId(), information.getStart(),
                    information.getEnd())) {
                             ...dostuff...
                    
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
```

which throws this exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: You're trying to execute a streaming query method without a surrounding transaction that keeps the connection open so that the Stream can actually be consumed. Make sure the code consuming the stream uses @Transactional or any other way of declaring a (read-only) transaction.
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$StreamExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:341)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.findObservationsByDatastreamIdAndPhenomenonStartAfterAndPhenomenonEndBefore(Unknown Source)
    at edu.teco.sensordatenbankmanagementsystem.services.ObservationServiceImp.lambda$createNewDataStream$1(ObservationServiceImp.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

At this line
`.findObservationsByDatastreamIdAndPhenomenonStartAfterAndPhenomenonEndBefore`(ObservationServiceImp.java:79)

I have already tried making the class transactional as well, which throws the same error.
The sensorservice.getDatastreams method is also transactional and my repository looks like this

```
@Repository
public interface ObservationRepository extends JpaRepository<Observation, String> {

  Optional<Observation> findById(String id);

  Stream<Observation> findObservationsByDatastreamIdAndPhenomenonStartAfterAndPhenomenonEndBefore(
      String dataStream, @Param("PhenomenonStart") LocalDateTime phenomenonStart,
      @Param("PhenomenonEnd") LocalDateTime phenomenonEnd);
    .
    .
    .

}
```

The repository has to return streams because the amount of data it returns exceeds the standard heap size in 1 call, and we suspect we need to handle up to 20 calls at the same time with varying size.

Comment: Your stream usage is useless as you are directly consuming it into a list, it doesn't add anything. Instead of collecting as a list, you should either iterate over it (or forgo streams and just directly query for the list). You also have an endless loop so it will indefinitely keep the transaction (and thus connection) open. You also shouldn't create a new executor each time as eventually you will run out of memory/threads.

Comment: @ M.Deinum I think you are referring to this: "    List<Datastream> datastreams = sensorService
        .getDatastreams(information.getSensors().get(0), information.getStart(),
            information.getEnd()).collect(Collectors.toList());"

Which yes it is directly consumed but it also isn't the one I am concerned with.

I will have to create a new execturo if they are supposed to all run asynchronous from each other do I not?

Edit: That first stream is currently a place holder as I was more concerned with trying to fix the problem at hand

Comment: @M.Deinum I have tried changing that Stream to a List and it results in the same problem I had before, so that does not seem to solve anything sadly.

Comment: The error you get is due to the new thread, a transaction is thread bound. As you start a new one, this doesn't have a transaction and thus you get this error. However imho your code is flawed and will grind your application to a halt after your connection pool has exhausted (default that is 10 connections).

Comment: How would I be able to have multiple different Emitters without putting them into different connections?

Comment: The problem, as iterated twice, is your indefinite while loop. It will eventually exhaust the pool and make your application unresponsive (for everyone else). You should rethink your solution to not block and indefinitely use a connection for this.

Comment: Oh I didn't gather that. The indefinite while loop is only indefinite in this short form here. It technically has to be cancelled with an exception because thats the way SSE apparently works

Comment: No that is not how the sse emmitter works. Why iterate over that list indefinitely in the first place? I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish here (and it looks overly complex as well).

Comment: I am not entirely certain if this is the place to explain. You defo. helped me immensely already. I am doing this as a project for university and the request is to be able to have a live replay system that polls the database more or less indefinetly. Tho while writing this I have thought of an implementation that works differently. It is unnecessarily complex but that might have something to do with the fact that the entire project which this is built upons uses no conventions what so ever.